# Why is there no MFCxx.dll in the import table?

Tags: disassembly, malware

I have an exe which I'm confident uses MFC(I have seen the code and it heavily uses MFC) but when I see the Import Table why don't I see  MFCxx.dll entry...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of three possibilities:

- It doesn't use MFC
- It uses MFC and the MFC functions are linked via [static libraries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_library)
- It uses MFC and the MFC DLLs are [dynamically loaded](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175.aspx) (or [delay-loaded](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx9zd12s.aspx)) at runtime

Comment: 4th possibility: The .exe uses MFC, but not directly; it might use a framework that builds on MFC. In this case, the .exe might just link in the framework dll, which then links the MFC dll. [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) is your friend in these cases.

Comment: _"(I have seen the code and it heavily uses MFC)"_ - I had assumed rebel87 meant in the EXE module itself, but if rebel87 meant that MFC code was just seen in the process's address space in general, then yes, @guntram-blohm, that's a 4th possibility.